# How to skip the method of a callback in rspec when there is no method name?

Tags: activerecord, rspec, callback

I have some callbacks like this:

```
after_destroy :send_email
```

And I can skip them in Rspec passing the name:

```
Model.skip_callback(:destroy, :after, :send_email)
```

But what if I have something like:

```
after_destroy { |instance| do_something(instance) }
```

How can I skip this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing before your test following line

```
ActiveRecord::Base.skip_callbacks = true
```

Now write your test and then enable callbacks by doing following.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.skip_callbacks = false
```

But I think it is not good thing to skip_callbacks.